# How to display count(*) in laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I got a response as follows. I need to the print the "count(*)" field along with some other data like "Duke (2)" where 2 is the count.
How can I print the value in the laravel template.

```
{
  parts_model_id: 8,
  parts_id: 29,
  parts_title: "duke multiple model",
  model_id: 1,
  model_name: "OPAH2",
  created_at: "2017-07-18 17:02:10",
  updated_at: "2017-07-18 17:02:10",
  count(*): 2
}
```

The code

```
$models = PartsModel::with('model')->selectRaw('*, count(*)')->groupBy('model_id')->get();
```

Thank you

Comment: We need to see how you're retrieving the results so we can advise you. Post some code. Are you using Eloquent or the query builder?

Comment: $models = PartsModel::with('model')->selectRaw('*, count(*)')->groupBy('model_id')->get();

Comment: What are you trying to count exactly?

Comment: i count model id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this :

```
$models = PartsModel::with('model')
                    ->selectRaw('*, count(*) AS countElements')
                    ->groupBy('model_id')
                    ->get();
```

And you can access the count using (after looping :)) :

```
$model->countElements;
```